# Incorrect cast - is it the cast or the use which is undefined behavior

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

If I do a cast from a Base to a Derived type, but the Base type isn't an instance of derived type, but only use the result if it is, do I get undefined behaviour?

Hard to understand what I'm asking? take a look at this example:

```
struct Animal { int GetType(){...} };
struct Dog : Animal { bool HasLoudBark(){...}};
struct Cat : Animal { bool HasEvilStare(){...} };

Animal * a = ...;
Dog* d = static_cast<Dog*>(a);

if(a->GetType() == DogType && d->HasLoudBark())
    ....
```

In this case `a` may or not be a `Dog`. We always do the `static_cast` of `a` to `Dog * d` but we never use `d` unless we're sure its a `Dog`.

Assuming that `a` is not a `Dog`, is this undefined behaviour at the point of the cast? Or is it defined as we don't actually use `d` unless it is really is a `Dog`?

References to the relevant parts of the standard are appreciated.

(Yes I know I can use dynamic_cast, and RTTI, and probably this isn't great code, but I'm more interested in whether this is valid)

Comment: Short answer; it is not valid. Longer answer; it depends on how all the missing parts are actually done. Please post a [mcve] that compiles.

Comment: @wally Normally I'm totally up for MVCE however I'm not convinced this is actually useful. I only really give the example code to help explain the question - I dont actually care about the included code. Infact, the opposite - I'd be extremely interested in the opposite - assuming reasonable implementations of Animal, Dog, Cat Id love to know what would make a difference with the answer as you say it would change it.

Comment: @wally I tweaked my question to hopefully make this clearer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The cast itself has undefined behaviour. Quoting C++17 (n4659) [expr.static.cast] 8.2.10/11:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`”, where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
>   to *cv2* `D`”, where `D` is a class derived (Clause 13) from `B`, if *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater
>   cv-qualification than, *cv1*. ... If the prvalue of
>   type “pointer to *cv1* `B`” points to a `B` that is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer
>   points to the enclosing object of type `D`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. Before I resolve, there is a comment from Wally saying that this depends. Can you see anything which would make this defined as your answer is pretty explicit? Also, "the behaviour is undefined" - does this mean the behaviour of the cast is undefined (in which case I'm ok as I dont use the result of it) or the whole program?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, OP would be safe with a `reinterpret_cast`, right?

Comment: @MikeVine I think undefined behavior means that your contract with the standard does not have to be honored for the whole program. In practice I don't see this formatting your cat.

Comment: @YSC :) yes I did, and it's a good answer (+1), but I had to read the quote several times to understand what it's about...

Comment: @user1810087 Very funny. The question says "References to the relevant parts of the standard are appreciated."

Comment: @MikeVine As soon as a program exhibits UB anywhere, the standard places no restrictions on its behaviour even *before* the UB construct is first reached at runtime. In other words, if a program has UB, all bets are off.

Comment: @Angew This also licenses compilers to assume that UB doesn't happen. So in the example code, the compiler can assume that `a` points to a `Dog`, and optimize `a->getType() == DogType` into `true`.

Answer (score 12):

[This is undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49981379/5470596), but (funny enough) if you would have used `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast`, you would cast that demon away.

> [`[expr.reinterpret.cast]/7`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#7)
>
> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue v of object pointer type is converted to the object pointer type “pointer to `cv T`”, the result is `static_­cast<cv T*>(static_­cast<cv void*>(v))`.

As noted by user Angew, this "requires a particular internal representation which ensures that `static_cast<void*>(d) == static_cast<void*>(a)` when `a == d`".

This is expressed by `[class.mem]/22` to `26`:

> [`[class.mem]/26`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#26)
>
> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member if that member is not a bit-field. Its address is also the same as the address of each of its base class subobjects.

So if `GetType()` of `Animal` returns the value of a non-static data member from the [*common initial sequence*](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#22) of `Animal` and `Dog`, the behavior is defined.

Those requirements are met when dealing with simple inheritance and default-aligned objects.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184529/discussion-on-answer-by-ysc-incorrect-cast-is-it-the-cast-or-the-use-which-is).