# static_cast dangling reference when downcasting

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Is the following code correct or does it yield undefined behavior due to a dangling reference and why exactly is it correct:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

B& f(A& a) {
  // Dangling reference here?
  return static_cast<B&>(a);    
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  B& b = f(a);
}
```

Comment: @Incomputable I double-checked and I think your "possible duplicate" was correct.

Comment: You are not creating any temporary object, so nothing dangles here

Comment: Both `a` refer to the same object, whose life-time ends on leaving `main`. `b` refers to a sub-object of `a`, whose life-time also ends on leaving `main`. So no dangling reference.

Comment: I checked the documentation of `static_cast`. What does **downcast** mean exactly in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour, but not because of a dangling reference. The act of casting an object using `static_cast` from a parent class to the child class when it is not actually that child is undefined behaviour:

```
 B& b = f(a); // Casts `A` type to `B` incorrectly
```

See the relevant standard quote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49981379/1294207).

Answer (score 0):

A dangling reference is a reference to an object that no longer exists.
In your code sample, there is no problem as A exists within the same scope as B and therefore the reference is always valid.

Now, take this modified example where delete the object A, after creating a reference to it. This is in fact a dangling reference and yields undefined behavior after object A is deleted.

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  int m;
};
class B : public A {};

B& f(A& a) {
  return static_cast<B&>(a);
}

int main()
{
  A *a = new A();
  a->m = 42;
  B& b = f(*a);
  std::cout << b.m << std::endl; // Valid                                       
  delete a; // Dangling reference created here                                
  std::cout << b.m << std::endl; // Undefined behavior                          
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sources?